# How run exe in InnoSetup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

does not run the command file.

```
ShellExec ('', ExpandConstant ('{src}\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe'),'','', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

it just passes it.

```
[Files]
    Source: C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TrainerRoomSetup\TrainerRoomSetup\Debug\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe');
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more info? is this code has to be inside [Code] section?

Comment: +1 Thank you, works! @YumYumYum: yes, in code-section. Please take a look at "Pascal Scripting: Extract TemporaryFile" section in inno setup docu. There is an example there.